# Stripe when succes payment get userId (custom Data)

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I can successfully receive payment in the application , i can see the results in server log and stripe dashboard. What I can't do is I want to use the id of the user who made the payment as a result of the successful payment.I'm using metadata on the checkout side, but I can't transfer it to the webhook.How can I send custom data to the webhook?

stripe.checkout.sesion :

```
exports.test = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  return new Promise(async (Resolve, Reject) => {
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    line_items: [
      {
        // Provide the exact Price ID (for example, pr_1234) of the product you want to sell
        price: 'price_1Mgx1cATB1Z',
        quantity: 1,

      },
    ],
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/girls`,
    cancel_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/cancel.html`,
    metadata:{"Test":"Success"},
  });
Resolve(session.id)
  })
})
```

stripeWebhook - payment_intent.succeeded (here I want to use the user's id (db id))

```
exports.stripeWebhook = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onRequest(async(req,res)=>{
  const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature'];
  let event;
const payloadData = req.rawBody
const payloadString = payloadData.toString()
  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(payloadString, sig, endpointSecret);
  } catch (err : any) {
    res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
    return;
  }

  switch (event.type) {
    case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
      const paymentIntentSucceeded = event.data.object;
      // Then define and call a function to handle the event payment_intent.succeeded
      console.log(paymentIntentSucceeded)
      break;
    // ... handle other event types
    default:
      console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}`);
  }
 res.send();
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

The issue here is that your metadata is set on the [Checkout Session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object), but the webhook event you are handling returns the [Payment Intent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object).  The metadata isn't automatically propagated between the Session and the Payment Intent.

### Solution

Use the `payment_intent_data.metadata` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-metadata) when you create the Checkout Session.  The data will be set on the Payment Intent when it gets created by the Session and it will show up in the Payment Intent object you receive for the `payment_intent.succeeded` event.